# "@model" not working on razor page in hybrid WebForm/MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm integrating MVC into our current .Net WebForms site.  I used these links for guidance while setting it up. [Hanselman - Integrating MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) and [blog.falafel](http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/BasemEmara/basem-emara/2012/09/27/integrating-asp.net-mvc-4-into-existing-web-forms-applications).

The site works and I can navigate to .aspx pages and controller/actions no problem.  But when I try to add the @model to a razor page, @model doesn't appear to be registering and Visual Studios sees  as a HTML5 item.

exception:

{"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET    Files\root\a3be471e\a209a63\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.d7uqhlro.0.cs(30): error CS1514: { expected"} System.Exception {System.Web.HttpCompileException}

I added all of the appropriate references and went over both sites multiple times.

List of references I added -

```
Microsoft.Csharp
System.ComponentModel.Data
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages
System.Net.Http
System.Web.Optimization
System.Web.Http
System.Web.Http.WebHost
Newtonsoft.Json
```

Web.config additions

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

<system.web>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
   </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>

<configuration>
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `@model doesn't appear to be registering` - What does that mean?  `and Visual Studios sees as a HTML5 item` - Again, what does that mean?  What's the error?  What's the output?

Comment: No one is going to be able to help you with this information, could you provide more? The web.configs in your root and Views folder would be a good start.

Comment: When I type in model in an MVC app, model is colored as a key word.  In the hybrid solution, the "at" sign highlights like it should but "model" appears as if it's just normal text.  Since model isn't registering as a keyword, VS sees the text between the <> as an HTML element and I get "Validation (XHTML5): Element blah.foo.bar is not supported."

I couldn't put the "at" sign because it thinks I'm replying to somebody. Sorry if that makes it confusing.

Comment: What is the extension of the file that VS doesn't like for your @model?

Comment: Do you have a web.config file in your Views folder? If so, post that as well. If not, then that might be the issue, as there is nothing to tell the web project that it should try to interpret Razor pages.

Comment: @VtoCorleone Can you post your view?

Comment: I got it to work by starting over in VS 2012 instead of 2010.  I'm going to try and compare the 2 solutions to see what the difference was and what mistake I made.  Thanks for the help!